# How to upload file to S3 from GAE (a horror story)

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3, jclouds

I am trying to upload a file to amazon S3 from GAE.

I tried the official amazon sdk ([jetS3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/toolkit.html), built on top of the [lower-level sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)), just to find out that even if you can get it to work locally by setting permissions on the local JVM it is not supported for GAE crypto-related reasons once you deploy it.

Then out of desperation I found that some good soul [forked the official low-level amazon sdk](https://github.com/apcj/aws-sdk-for-java-on-gae) so that it would work with GAE. This kind of works (even though I can see some strage NullPointer exceptions being thrown here and there) and the file gets uploaded ... but if the file size exceeds 5MB I am getting a error from within the API:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call urlfetch.Fetch() was too large
```

I don't fully understand this as the current GAE limitations seem to be 32MB on file size upload and 1MB on request/response while my problem is occurring only when the file is around 5MB or bigger.

I think my only alternative left is [jclouds](http://www.jclouds.org/), but I am having trouble finding examples of uploading files to S3 using the BlobStore library.

**Does anyone have experience/examples to share of S3 file upload with jClouds? And am I likely to incur in the same** `urlfetch.Fetch() was too large` **error?**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URLFetch requests are limited to 5MB, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits). The only solutions that will work are those that involve breaking up a large payload into smaller chunks. Fortunately, S3 provides a [multipart upload API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html).

Comment: Thanks Nick - let's see if I can get the multipart upload API to play nicely with app-engine :)

Comment: @JohnIdol Have you considered just writing the code yourself? The RESTful API is pretty straightforward - the only complexity is computing the header signature, and there's probably a library that will do that for you.

Comment: I am keeping that for the all-else-fails scenario :) Now I am giving it another shot with the 'low-level' aws API approach (the 'high level' approach fails with all sorts of 'access denied' issues).

Answer (score 1):

On the [release notes for 1.5.0](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/app-engine-150-release.html), I read *In response to popular demand, the HTTP request and response sizes have been increased to 32 MB.* So, request and response, URL fetch is not mentioned.

Indeed, looking at [URL Fetch documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits), it says it's max 5 Mb.